# Why my code produce an incorrect graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, figure

Does anyone know why my MATLAB code is give an incorrect graph?

I want to plot f(x)=exp(-x)-2*x.

The codes as follows.

```
clear all;
clc;
h=0.01;
x=-1:h:1;
f=exp(-x)-2*x;
plot(f,x,'color','r');
grid on;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
```

This code  give me a figure like this.

[image]

We know f(0)=1. But in the graph f(0) not equal to 1. Does anyone know why my code produce an incorrect graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis on your graph are inverted. The line that says

```
plot(f,x,'color','r');
```

should be:

```
plot(x,f,'color','r');
```

The plot function expects first the abscissa (x) and then the ordinate (f).